# Error iframe does not scroll in Chrome when using facebook comment?

Tags: php, css, iframe, stylesheet, facebook-comments

I added an iframe facebook comment, in Firefox it scrolls, but in Chrome it does not, How do I fix it ?

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=172666652872245&amp;channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D27%23cb%3Df3a81f3cfd7ece2%26domain%3Ddevelopers.facebook.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdevelopers.facebook.com%252Ff1b19ded3a3bee%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;href=http://dongcam.vn/t84630&amp;locale=vi_VN&amp;numposts=10&amp;sdk=joey&amp;width=550"
 scrolling="yes"
 frameborder="0"
 style="border:none; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; min-height: 100%; width: 470px; background: #FFF;"
 allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `min-height:100%`

here's a JS bin:

http://jsbin.com/oBITUkE/1/edit